# как изменить функцию что бы она принимала разные аргументы

Tags: javascript

Счас она выдает по firstName с удалением повторяемых, а надо еще чтобы с age выдавало. Или как изменить чтобы от tName она везде  в функции принимало от него значение firstName

```js
var persons = [
  { firstName : "Goуsho", lastName: "Peкtrov", age: 32 },
  { firstName : "Baуy", lastName: "Ivaкn", age: 81 },

  { firstName : "Bayв", lastName: "Ivкan", age: 81 },
  { firstName : "Vinnвy", lastName: "pкuh", age: 15 }

];
function groupPeople(obj, tName){
  
var names = obj.slice(0);
var eeee = names.filter(function(item, tName) {
  var b=0;
return names.findIndex(el => el.firstName == item.firstName) == tName;

})
console.log(eeee);
var i=0;
for ( name in eeee) {
   
  var value = eeee[i++].firstName;
  name = +name; // 
  
  var  ddd = value ; 

  console.log(ddd);
  
}}

var grorstName = groupPeople (persons, "firstName");
//var groupeAge = groupPeople (persons, "age");
```

Comment: "а надо еще чтобы с age выдавало" - ??

Comment: да, изменил вопрос

Comment: лучше не стало (

Comment: что с разными вызовами функций работало как будто с перегрузкой. 1 вызов работает 2 не хочет я не знаю как изменить чтобы от 2 аргумента arguments[1] принимало

Comment: Проще как изменить el.firstName item.firstName и eeee[i++].firstName на значение из вызова функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var persons = [
  { firstName : "Gosho", lastName: "Petrov", age: 32 },
  { firstName : "Bay", lastName: "Ivan", age: 81 },
  { firstName : "Bay", lastName: "Ivan", age: 81 },
  { firstName : "Vinny", lastName: "puh", age: 15 }
];

function groupItems(arr, prop) {
  var res = [];
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (res.indexOf(item[prop]) == -1)
      res.push(item[prop]);
  });
  return res;
}

var a = groupItems(persons, "firstName");
console.log(a);
var b = groupItems(persons, "age");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: должно выдовать в 1 случаи //Gosho, Bay, Vinny

Comment: а во 2 -м 32,81,15

Comment: как сделать чтобы el.firstName item.firstName и eeee[i++].firstName они принимали значение аргумента, тогда можно будет и изменить что бы age принимало

Comment: @recile кажется, понял )

Comment: супер, спасибо большое